# Weird white line on top of Action Bar

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I implemented a `DrawerNavigationView` with a `BottomNavigationView` at the same time, but the problem is the **`ActionBar`**... The default fragment is ok [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8aNp.jpg) But changing `fragment` it creates a weird white line on the top of the `ActionBar`, which is not anymore in the right position... Do u maybe know why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6mT.jpg) Thank u for help D:

**XML Code for main activity container for fragments**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:theme="@style/Theme2"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white_darker"
        app:itemRippleColor="@color/white_darker"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white_darker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemTextAppearance="?textAppearanceListItem"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

**XML code for fragment with the problem (Empty ConstraintLayout)**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/dark"
tools:context=".HomeUi.Notifications.NotificationsFragment">
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: can you please share your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who has the same problem in future I found the solution adding as a root a CoordinatorLayout wrapping all the xml code on the main fragment container and using android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on it, everything working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

In your `styles.xml` file try `NoActionBar` after the `parent`. Other problem could be that there is a rest of a `linearlayout` in your `fragment`.

Comment: what u mean with "rest"? ps: if I use NoActionBar it doesnt compile because of drawer navigation looking for the actionbar

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing it in plain activity using `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`. Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` both in `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` does the trick.

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       >
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    ...

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```